# How to join two table with partial match

Tags: sql, join, replace

I have two table with the following data:

```
TableA.name
R4.23-Core-2
R4.23-Core-2
LA#213 CGHPBXsw01 127.213 0024-737e-e341
LA#252 CGHRack1sw01 127.252 0022-57ab-d781
SOC-01A-SW01
to - R4-DISTR-9512
to-R2-DISTR-5900-1
to-R3.25-EDGE

TableB.caption
R4.23-Core-2.ehd.ca
R4.23-Core-2.nhd.ca
CGHPBXsw01
CGHRack1sw01
SOC-01A-SW01
R4-DISTR-9512
R2-DISTR-5900-1.phsnc.
R3.25-EDGE.phsne.edjc.ca
```

I've tried using the following join statement but it doesn't seem to work for any row with a . in it.

```
dbo.TableA.Name 
INNER JOIN dbo.TableB.Caption 
  ON dbo.TableA.Name LIKE '%' + dbo.TableB.Caption + '%'
```

I also try using replace function, which work but there are too much variant to include with replace.

I could try using the RIGHT or LEFT function to normalize the data but for row that doesn't have '.' it would throw an error. And I don't know how to skip row that doesn't have '.'

What is the most efficient way to join these two table?

Comment: That join should work.  Which item in TableA is not matching in TableB specifically?

Comment: Why dont you add a column with some sort of ids and join on that.

Comment: @user3072241 If I understand you correctly, you are trying to join the rows in A with the rows in B where the Caption column in B is fully contained within the Name column of A? That's what your join expression says anyway. I tried this in SQL Fiddle (SQL Server 2012) and it works as I would expect it to. Are you using a different database?

Comment: Well, you join on tables not columns so you at least have to change it to `dbo.TableA INNER JOIN dbo.TableB` and then specify your join condition.

Comment: The join statement work but it would omit out all the row that have '.' for example (R4.23-Core-2.nhd.ca)

Comment: It should omit out that row from TableB, because `R4.23-Core-2 <> %R4.23-Core-2.nhd.ca%`.  Look at the answer from @goat-co.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some situations in your example the caption is longer, and other times the name is longer, if you wanted to join on any value where name is in the caption or caption is in the name you could use:

```
dbo.TableA.Name 
INNER JOIN dbo.TableB.Caption 
   ON   dbo.TableA.Name LIKE '%' + dbo.TableB.Caption + '%'
     OR dbo.TableB.Caption LIKE '%' + dbo.TableA.Name + '%'
```

That could explain why your query isn't working as expected.

As far as the most efficient way to do this, you'd want to have a standardized field in your table that you could use to `JOIN` on via equality (ex. a.col1 = b.col1), so that would entail stripping out the heart of each field that makes it join-worthy.

Update:  If the important part is everything before the first period, then you want to use a combination of `LEFT()` and `CHARINDEX()` (and a `CASE` statement since not all strings contain a period):

```
SELECT NewField = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',Name) > 0 THEN  LEFT(Name,CHARINDEX('.',Name)-1) 
                       ELSE Name
                  END
FROM YourTable
```

You could use the above in your `JOIN` too:

```
dbo.TableA.Name 
INNER JOIN dbo.TableB.Caption 
  ON CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',TableA.Name) > 0 THEN  LEFT(TableA.Name,CHARINDEX('.',TableA.Name)-1) 
                           ELSE TableA.Name
                      END
    = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('.',TableB.Caption) > 0 THEN  LEFT(TableB.Caption,CHARINDEX('.',TableB.Caption)-1) 
                           ELSE TableB.Caption
                      END
```

Comment: I do want to standardized this and tried using RIGHT function:

Comment: Can you describe what portion of the field value is the important part?

Comment: So I tried to standarized TableB

    TableB.caption
    R4.23-Core-2.ehd.ca
    R4.23-Core-2.nhd.ca
    CGHPBXsw01
    CGHRack1sw01
    SOC-01A-SW01
    R4-DISTR-9512
    R2-DISTR-5900-1.phsnc.
    R3.25-EDGE.phsne.edjc.ca

using 
    LEFT (dbo.TableB.Caption, CHARINDEX('.', dbo.TableB.Caption) - 1)

But I get error when it reach any row that doesn't have the '.' for example CGHPBXsw01 

The only way i know to get pass this error is using NULLIF but this would return NULL to that row and not the actual row value

Comment: the important part are everything before the first '.'

Comment: That case statement work perfectly!!! Is it possible to do a nest case? if I have some row that is in IP format? like 10.1.1.1

Comment: You can nest a case or add additional `WHEN..THEN` pairs to it to handle every situation.

Answer (score 0):

How about this ( Not Tested)

```
dbo.TableA
INNER JOIN dbo.TableB 
      ON CHARINDEX(dbo.TableB.Caption, dbo.TableA.Name) > 0
```

Test it and don't forget Upvote OR accept.