# Querying multiple tables for text strings that are similar

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I'm working on an application that uses Postgres for the database.  I'm at the point where I need to query the data contained in multiple tables and even multiple databases.

I'm still learning the syntax of PostgreSQL queries, so hopefully this question is structured correctly.

I would like to query 2 tables for a text string contained in a specific column. 
In the example code, below I'm attempting to query table_1 and table_2 for the fruit name 'apple' or a fruit name similar to 'apple,' such as 'crabapple.'  I would like one of the string to be loose and the other to be explicit.

I can query each table individually, but how do I cross-reference the 'fruit_name' in both tables for similarities?

```
SELECT * FROM good_fruits where fruit_name ILIKE '%apple%'
SELECT * FROM bad_fruits where fruit_name ILIKE '%apple%'
```

I have tried to do something similar using the query below, but it doesn't work.
How should a query be structured to query two tables for similar text in a single column named fruit_name?

```
select 
good_fruits.bar_code,
good_fruits.fruit_name, 
bad_fruits.fruit_name
from good_fruits full outer join bad_fruits
on good_fruits.fruit_name=bad_fruits.fruit_name 
WHERE good_fruits.fruit_name IS NOT NULL 
and bad_fruits.fruit_name IS NOT NULL
and good_fruits.fruit_name ILIKE '%apple%'
and bad_fruits.fruit_name ILIKE '%apple%'
```

I plan to make this query using a Python script with the psycopg2 module.  The returned results should be:

```
good_fruits.barcode, good_fruits.fruit_name, bad_fruits.fruit_name
```

Comment: Your question can be interpreted in several ways. Can you add an example with the posible content of both tables and the result that you want? (The result can be anohter "table like" report).

Comment: I plan to make this query from python using psycopg2.  The results from this query will be processed as a list.  The table names and the column names listed above are sanitized, so it's hard to post the content of my tables.

Comment: I'm currently using python and psycopg2 to perform various database operations.

Comment: You can see how to show an example of the result you expect see at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950317/postgresql-combining-several-periods-into-one/51951406#51951406   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950434/set-attribute-value-if-correct-type/51950517#51950517  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730792/split-column-into-two-columns-in-a-migration/50731540#50731540  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958137/postgres-trigger-function-to-update-aggregated-result-in-another-table/47963640#47963640

Comment: I updated my question with how I currently plan to use this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need just to give pseudonyms to your output columns:

```
select 
good_fruits.bar_code as "good_fruits.bar_code",
good_fruits.fruit_name as "good_fruits.fruit_name", 
bad_fruits.fruit_name as "bad_fruits.fruit_name"
from good_fruits full outer join bad_fruits
on good_fruits.fruit_name=bad_fruits.fruit_name 
WHERE good_fruits.fruit_name IS NOT NULL 
and bad_fruits.fruit_name IS NOT NULL
and good_fruits.fruit_name ILIKE '%apple%'
-- and bad_fruits.fruit_name ILIKE '%apple%' -- you can omit this condition
```

You can shorten this by giving pseudonyms to the table names too:

```
select 
    g.bar_code as "good_fruits.bar_code",
    g.fruit_name as "good_fruits.fruit_name", 
    b.fruit_name as "bad_fruits.fruit_name"
from 
   good_fruits g
   full outer join bad_fruits b
       on g.fruit_name=b.fruit_name 
WHERE g.fruit_name IS NOT NULL 
and b.fruit_name IS NOT NULL
and g.fruit_name ILIKE '%apple%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  For some reason, my query is returning no results.  I know that I can query each table individually and get results.   I assume that I can query the fruit_name column in both tables and get the rows that have similar text, such as apple in the fruit_name column.

Comment: The g.fruit_name=b.fruit_name condition joins tables by exact match. Probably, this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412170/how-to-join-two-table-with-partial-match

Comment: The items are NOT exact, so that could be my issue.  I will do some more research. Thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: Your code example worked when I modified the = and ILIKE qualifiers with either ILIKE or ~*.  I will need to do some more testing, because I have fruit_names in one table formatted like this 'apples' and the other table formatted like this 'Fuji Apples' or 'Apple Fuji'.  So the differently formatted fruit_names don't link up across the tables.  I need 'apples' and Fuji Apples' or 'Apple Fuji' to be associated  in my returning results.  Is this possible?

Comment: @Lifeiscomplex Compare strings, for example, in lower case, i.e. use 'lower' function when comparing: lower(g.fruit_name) ILIKE ...

Comment: Thanks for the pointer about the lowercase function in the query.